# Check if there are any repeated elements in an array recursively

Tags: c#, java, recursion

I have to find recursively if there is any repeated element in an integer array `v`.
The method must have the following signature:

```
boolean hasRepeatedElements(int[] v)
```

I can't see any way of doing that recursively without having to define another method or at least another overload to this method (one that takes for example the element to go after or something). At first I thought about checking for the current `v` if there is some element equal to the first element, then creating a new array with `L-1` elements etc. but that seems rather inefficient. Is it the only way?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why does it have to be recursive?

Comment: because it is homework/exam-like-question?

Comment: Sounds like a sieve job-interview question too.

Comment: @chibacity: I'm guessing homework.

Comment: ok, but either way i'd like to know people opinions on it. i guess they want me to make an array copy at each method call, but that doesn't seem like a great idea to me :(

Comment: Don't use recursion, you might, wait for it... get a stack overflow...

Comment: requiring recursion is a stupid requirement.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat. If it's an interview question, then maybe that's what it's getting at.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Agreed. It seems like a very weird question all round.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that recursion is not terribly necessary here, but it can be used.
Do you know quick-sort algorithm? Same divide-and-conquer approach can be taken here.

```
boolean hasRepeatedElements(list v) 
    if v.length <= 1 return false;
    List less, greater;
    x = v[0];
    for each y in v, except v[0]
        if y == x
            return true;
        else if y < x
            less.add(y);
        else if y > x
            greater.add(y);
    end;
    return hasRepeatedElements(less) || hasRepeatedElements(greater);
end;
```

You can also add randomization to make algorithm statistically O(n*log(n)).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: Maybe I'm supposed to use this approach. At least the quick-sort is part of this course's syllabus.

Comment: Mon Dieue - of course I can see that. It's just the question says "The method must have the following signature: boolean hasRepeatedElements(int[] v)". :)

Comment: +1. The average time bounds for this match(or perhaps beat!) the worst case lower bound for this problem: Element Distinctness Problem, see: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_uniqueness_problem

Comment: @Nikita: You don't really need to add randomization to make this average case O(nlogn). If input is random enough...

Comment: A simple solution would be to create a list of the array and a set from the list, and see if the size of the list was the same as the size of the array.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure someone out there smarter than me could do this more efficiently, but at least it works.

```
bool hasRepeatedElements(int[] v)
        {
            if (v.Length > 1)
            {
                int[] subArray = new int[v.Length - 1];
                for (int i = 1; i < v.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (v[0] == v[i])
                        return true;
                    else
                        subArray[i - 1] = v[i];
                }
                return hasRepeatedElements(subArray);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating would be quicker. Or using container class. Your way will work, but won't be very efficient. If this was C, instead of copying you could just call hadRepeatedElements(v + 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort and compare at the same time, since that's effectively what a sorting algorithm would be doing. If your sorting algorithm is recursive you win :)

```
boolean hasRepeatedElements(int[] v) {
  if (v.length <= 1) return false;
  boolean switched = false;
  int[] sub = new int[v.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
    sub[i] = v[i];
  for (int i = 0; i < sub.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sub[i] > sub[i + 1]) {
      switched = true;
      int temp = sub[i];
      sub[i] = sub[i + 1];
      sub[i + 1] = temp;
    } 
    else if (sub[i] == sub[i + 1]) return true;
  }
  if (!switched) return false; //We have not sorted the array and found zero dups

  return hasRepeatedElements(sub); //The recursive bit
```

}

If you think this looks hurried it is, I have a flight to catch. The basic principal is there, someone here could almost certainly refine the code :)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it *must* be recursive with that signature...

You could also sort the array and compare the first two elements.  Then make a recursive call with elements [1..n].

Comment: Yes, but as stated, I'd need to define another method, or at least another overload to do that.

Comment: Why?  What would this other method do?

Comment: I misread your post. So basically you're saying the same everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like sorting, then this solution solves it without sorting.  You should be able to make it much more efficient.

```
boolean hasRepeatedElements(int[] v) 
{
    if ( v . length <= 1 )
    {
        return ( false ) ;
    }
    int k = RANDOM . nextInt ( v . length ) ;
    int leftLength = v . length / 2 ;
    int [ ] left = new int [ leftLength ] ;
    int rightLength = v . length - l ;
    int [ ] rightLength = new int [ rightLength ] ;
    int i , l , r ;
    for ( i = 0 , l = 0 , r = 0 ; i < v . length ; i ++ )
    {
        if ( ( v [ i ] < v [ k ] ) & ( l < leftLength ) )
        {
            left [ l ] = v [ i ] ;
            l ++ ;
        }
        else if ( ( v [ i ] >= v [ k ] ) & ( r < rightLength ) )
        {
            right [ r ] = v [ i ] ;
            r ++ ;
        }
        else
        {
            return ( hasRepeatedElements ( v ) ) ;
        }
    }
    if ( hasRepeatedElements ( left ) ) { return ( true ) ; }
    if ( hasRepeatedElements ( right ) ) { return ( true ) ; }
    return ( false ) ;
}
```

This solution is not very efficient, but it uses recursion and it follows the method signature exactly.

```
static java . util . Random RANDOM = new java . util . Random ( ) ;

boolean hasRepeatedElements(int[] v) 
{
     int s = Random . nextInt ( v . length ) ;
     int t = Random . nextInt ( v . length ) ;
     int temp = v[s] ;
     v[s] = v[t] ;
     v[t] = temp ;
     for ( int i = 0 ; i < v . length - 1 ; i ++ )
     {
          if ( v[i]==v[i+1] ) { return true ; }
          else if ( v[i]>v[i+1] { return hasRepeatedElements ( v ) ; }
     }
     return false ;
}
```